# Wamp server does not display any files and displays only directory names

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

Wamp server does not display any files and displays only directory names. When I click on the directory name, that displays no files inside the directory. When I check the apache error log it says that "File does not exists". But at the same time it works on my local. I have this problem only when I host into the server.

Comment: did you try to enter absolute path of the file

Comment: yes i did. it takes lot of time and display white blank page. when i check the apache error log again "Execution time exceeds" it shows.

Comment: @mrdhana "Execution time exceeds" i am only guessing you are in require loop. file A requires file B then B requires A

Comment: Make a test page that prints `phpinfo()`. This will prove that PHP is working and that your web server is able to reply to requests.

Comment: @Peter any single page is visible. if i try full path also, it is not working.

Comment: @doveyg i also tried with that. can not access that file also

Comment: In that case, what happens when you browse `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @doveyg displays only project directories

Comment: What version of WAMP are you running? Also, can you uninstall all components and try re-installing? I have heard this fixes things sometimes.

Comment: Just checking here: Is there a file called `index.php` in the `\wamp\www` folder

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes i have, but i could not access that file also

Comment: Then when you enter `http://localhost` in the browser address bar, do you see the wampserver homepage?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It displayes as follows  
[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description

Comment: Then you have overwritten the WAMPServer homepage code with who knows what! Have you made any changes else where in WAMPServer like the `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes i have made some changes in httpd.conf file.

Comment: In that case you ought to tell us EXACTLY what you are running (WAMPSERVERE VERSION) and EXACTLY what you changed from the default installation. Then we can offer some useful answers and not just guesses based on lack of information